# Generating only positive random numbers in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, random

In SQLite

> The `random()` function returns a pseudo-random integer between -9223372036854775808 and +9223372036854775807.

You can get an random with maximum value n with `Select random() % n ;`

But that still generates negative numbers. How can I generate only positive random numbers in SQLite ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the [`ABS()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) (absolute value) function:

```
SELECT ABS(RANDOM() % N)
```

Note that:

> If X is the integer -9223372036854775808 then `abs(X)` throws an integer overflow error since there is no equivalent positive 64-bit two's complement value.

Answer (score 15):

For generating **positive(including zero)** random number with only upper bound, use

```
SELECT ABS(RANDOM() % N)
```

For generating **positive** and **non-zero** random number, use

```
SELECT ABS(RANDOM()) % (HIGH - LOW) + LOW
```

**HIGH** - represents upper bound

**LOW** - represents lower bound.

Answer (score 7):

Your method `random() % n` for getting a random number within a certain range is flawed, as it will give an uneven distribution. The number zero will come up twice as often as any other number.

Incidentally, using `ABS` to make the numbers positive is flawed in the exact opposite way, making the number zero turn up half as often as any other number, so they cancel each other out.

```
abs(random() % n)
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa, but where's the solution ?

Comment: The soultion is `abs(random() % n)`.

Comment: "Your method random() % n for getting a random number within a certain range is flawed, as it will give an uneven distribution. The number zero will come up twice as often as any other number." Wow. That was a good insight.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ABS(RANDOM() % N)
```

and

```
SELECT ABS(RANDOM()) % N
```

both **tend** to give the desired result.

To my eye, the second is more readable. First we pseudo randomly select an integer, then we apply ABS() insure it's non-negative, then we modulo this by N to select the appropriate range.

However, the first method is more reliable. The second method has a very low, but non zero, risk of throwing an integer overflow, as noted by NullUserException.